# Exception in Python Exception Class's __str__ Missed

Tags: python, exception

Does anybody know how to catch exceptions in python Exception's derived classes's `__str__` function? And how to debug that `__str__` using pdb since I find it doesn't work when invoke `pdb.set_trace()` or setting breakpoint in pdb in function `__str__`.

Example code:

```
class Ex(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        raise KeyError('1')

raise Ex()
```

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./exex.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise Ex()
__main__.Ex
```

While I think the output should be something like

```
KeyError: '1'
```

And if I add `pdb.set_trace()` before `raise KeyError('1')`, python runtime does not interrupt at `pdb.set_trace()`. So does anyone know how to debug `Exception.__str__` when it is a little complex?

---

Sorry for the `pdb.set_trace()` case. It works. However, if you forget to put `import pdb`, then python slightly ignore the exception which looks like `pdb.set_trace()` is ignored.

While setting breakpoint in pdb still does not work.

Comment: What would be the purpose of raising an exception there?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not my intention to raise an exception there. My `__str__` function is so complex that it may contain some bug which causes python runtime to raise some system exceptions. I want to debug those bugs.

Comment: Well doesn't *that* sound like a nightmare. Have you considered making the actual method simpler, and using a separate method to get further information?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Really a nightmare. So I asked here to see if there is any method to debug code in `__str__`. To use a separate method requires changing the program's design which is another nightmare.

Comment: @writalnaie it shouldn't need to change any design. You can split a method into multiple methods without changing the API or affecting the rest of the program.

Comment: @Trengot Raising an exception not only informs you about the exception's information, but provides an opportunity to breakpointing and debugging at the raising context in pdb. This changed design loses the latter functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `__str__` to get a message. Just do:

```
class Ex(Exception):
   pass

raise Ex('Key Error 1')
```

Prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise Ex('Key Error 1')
__main__.Ex: Key Error 1
```

Comment: My intention is not raising an exception with correct format. I want to debug the exception in `__str__`.

Comment: Don't raise an exception to do that -- use a breakpoint or well selected print statements...

Comment: Thanks, I tried pdb.set_trace() or adding breakpoint in `__str__`. Neither of them works. Actually I don't know where to add the print statements when function `__str__` slightly raises Exception that is impossible to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Python handles exceptions differently because it's in the process of printing an exception. Acknowledging another exception at that point would only to confuse the programmer, so Python swallows it and does the best it can.

Write your classes' `__str__` to always return a string and you'll be happier.

Comment: I know that I can simply return a string in `__str__`. But my returned string is produced by a very complex function that potentially contains bugs such as KeyError (referencing some key that does not exists in a dict). That's the reason I have to debug `__str__` function.

Comment: Then catch those errors yourself and handle them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's a little difficult to statically find the errors myself without actually running the code since the `__str__` returned string's generating function is very complex.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the other day. I ended up wrapping my exception's `__str__` method in a try/except block. Something like this:

```
import traceback

class ex(Exception):
    def do_str(self):
        return "ex: %s" % self.notexist

    def check_str(self):
        try:
            return self.do_str()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            raise

    __str__ = check_str

raise ex()
```

Which when you run it prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t100.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ex()
__main__.exTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "t100.py", line 9, in check_str
    return self.do_str()
  File "t100.py", line 5, in do_str
    return "ex: %s" % self.notexist
AttributeError: 'ex' object has no attribute 'notexist'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works. I re-tried the `pdb.set_trace()` method, it also works providing that you don't forget to `import pdb`.  So maybe your same problem is also forgetting `import pdb`?

Comment: In my case I just wanted the traceback. That's what you want to do first, as it will catch mistakes like forgetting to `import pdb` or the couple of bugs I found in my example code before I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there's a Python bug I opened some while ago which at least makes the output a little bit less confusing: [issue22836](http://bugs.python.org/issue22836) .

There's also a patch, but unfortunately it's not merged so far.